# Automatically mount a remote folder on boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mount, sshfs

I'm trying to mount a Windows folder on my Ubuntu machine on start up. I've tried following this page [here](http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-mount-remote-directory-over-ssh-on-linux.html), modifying /etc/fstab and appending `sshfs#my_user@remote_host:/path/to/directory <local_mount_point> fuse user 0 0` to it, but it fails; on start up, I get an error saying that the mounting failed, and I can press S to skip or M to recover manually.

I also tried following this page [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/mounting-remote-directories-with-sshfs-on-ubuntu-11.10), appending `/usr/bin/sshfs -o idmap=user my_user@remote_host:/path/to/directory <local_mount_point>` to the /etc/rc.local file, but this doesn't help either; Ubuntu just boots up normally without mounting.

I have Cygwin installed on my Windows machine, and I can run everything smoothly, such as sshing without passwords, and mounting it manually. I've also tried to run the modified rc.local file `$ /etc/rc.local`, and it works perfectly, but I just can't seem to get the folder mounted on start up.

Can someone help me?

EDIT: by remote, I meant that the folder I'm trying to mount from my Windows machine (which has a public ip), is not on the same network. I am using sshfs, not nfs.

Comment: Could you please check whether the solution that works on my Arch system, which I just added to my initial answer as an edit, works for you too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu machine, I modified my /etc/fstab by adding this line:

```
 //192.168.xx.yy/Public /mnt/PUBNAS nfs rw,_netdev,credentials=/home/myname/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

The file .smbcredentials is very simple,

```
 username=myusername                                                                            
 password=mypassword
```

Edit:

After realizing that you use sshfs, I have tested the /etc/fstab entry suggested by [the Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs). For me, this entry worked:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs  defaults,_netdev  0  0
```

It is important that you have passwordless access to the server (*i.e.*, with cryptographic key). I hope this makes up for my initial blunder.

Edit 2:

If you want the remote folder to be mounted by you, not by root, which is admittedly a nuisance, you will have to change the /etc/fstab line to this:

```
 USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs _netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

Comment: He's using sshfs, not nfs. Relevant is just `_netdev`.

Comment: Absolutely:) Do you know if that option "_netdev" is used by some service later, to actually mount that path after network is established?

Comment: Is this still relevant to me, as I am using sshfs, not nfs? Also, my Windows machine is remote; it is not on the same network.

Comment: I modifed my /etc/fstab to include the line like this now: `sshfs#my_user@remote_host:/path/to/directory <local_mount_point> fuse user,_netdev 0 0`, but it doesn't work. I want to highlight though, that if I use the graphical method, and click the mount icon on my left panel, it works. I can now access it through terminal. However before using the graphical method, I couldn't access through terminal.

Comment: Also, is there a way to include the sshfs option `-o idmap=user` in the `/etc/fstab` file? When I move files from local to the mounted folder, I get the `mv: failed to preserve ownership` message.

Comment: I have passwordless access to server. I tried what you suggested, and the result is the same as the second comment above this one -- when I use terminal to try and access the mount point, its empty. But after I click the mount icon on the navigation panel on the left in the Ubuntu GUI, it mounts successfully. After which, when I try to access the mount point, all the files are there. Also, I'm mounting my server to my home folder in Ubuntu: ~/windows, and not in /mnt. Does this matter?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it works; however, I'm prompted for my password to the remote server (even though I can ssh in without any password). The remote folder is successfully mounted, but seems like I need root access to do anything. Trying to `cd` into the mounted folder gives me `Permission denied`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Are USER_ID_N and USER_GID_N variables I need to change? Also, does the `identityfile` have to be rsa? My key is a dsa private key. Should I generate an rsa one?

Comment: It doesn't work now. When I click the mount icon on the navigation panel on the left, nothing happens too.

Comment: `testsvr@203.125.xxx.yyy:/cygdrive/c/images  /home/andrew/windows  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/andrew/.ssh/key,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

Comment: After typing in `sudo mount -a` it works!! Is there a way to do `sudo mount -a` on start up automatically, so I don't have to log in and run it myself?

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm now! Just 2 quick questions - if say I were to do this with a Linux machine rather than a Windows machine, after changing the username/ip address/path to folder, would it still work? Secondly, how can I unmount the folder? I tried `fusermount -u ~/windows` and I get `fusermount: entry for /home/andrew/windows not found in /etc/mtab`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I've accepted this as answer, and I'd upvote if I could, but I have insufficient rep ;( Anyway, thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually looked closer at your scenario here, and I am wondering if you made sure to add the execute bit to that /etc/rc.local file you created originally (at the end of the howtoforge.com article you followed)

`chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Now reboot.

Comment: It seems like the file is already executable `$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 497 Oct 29 18:07 /etc/rc.local
andrew@Andrew-Ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
andrew@Andrew-Ubuntu:~$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 497 Oct 29 18:07 /etc/rc.local
` nothing changed when I used your command, but I'll try and reboot now anyway and see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify rc.local is being executed at boot? Put something in it:

echo 'test' >> /tmp/my.log

Next, see if there's any error output, append to your mount command:

&> /tmp/my.log

Perhaps when you manually execute the file, you're running it as a different user than the kernel is running it as. In that case a message would be written to STDERR, which you would typically see in /var/log/messages unless you redirect it elsewhere with the above syntax appended to the command.

Comment: I've done what you have suggested, and after rebooting, the file `/tmp/my.log` is created, but it's empty. `test` isn't inside the file, and `ls -l /tmp/my.log` gives me `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 31 09:31 /tmp/my.log`. I also have no file named `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: The user its running as may not have access to /tmp/, can you chmod 777 a folder, touch a file in it, chmod that 777 and try logging to a file there?

Comment: Yes, rc.local is executed at boot. Anyway, I've solved the problem. Thank you!