# Automount sshfs using fstab without mount -a

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sshfs, fuse

Please consider following fstab line (line breaks for readability):

```
sshfs#user@192.168.1.123:/home/user/ 
/home/user/Server/ 
fuse    
auto,user,_netdev,reconnect,uid=1000,gid=1000,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,idmap=user,allow_other  
0
```

It works fine, but every reboot I need to use `mount -a` to mount the server (or click appropriate icon in Thunar to mount the thing)

Is it possible to mount my ssh directory straight-away on boot time?

I am using Xubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 22):

The correct syntax for mounting sshfs shares at boot, in the /etc/fstab file is

```
 USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs _netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

It is an adaptation to **non-systemd** distros of the instructions contained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs). If you are instead on a **systemd** distro (Arch, Fedora, OpenSUSE,...), the suitable instruction is:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

Comment: It looks like almost exactly same fstab line as mine (except permissions and symlink option) Anyway I tried it, and no success. I still have to exec `mount -a` after boot

Comment: That's funny, it just worked for another user http://superuser.com/questions/666739/automatically-mount-a-remote-folder-on-boot/666775#666775. Have you checked that you are user 1000,1000, and that your key in id_rsa?

Comment: Yes, and it is working 100%, but I need to run `mount -a` after boot. I'm concidering to add `mount -a` to autostart

Comment: It is possible this occurs before your network comes up after execution of mount at boot. Try adding these two lines in rc.local   sleep 10: mount -a

Comment: Still no success. Perpaphs the issue is my configuration - my ethernet network is up 5-15 seconds after xfce (and desktop env.) is up. I don't know why ubuntu works like this. My arch connects before xfce etc.

Comment: What is relevant to you is whether this can be done at all during boot. So, perhaps you may try sleep 120; mount -a, just to see whether the diagnosis above is correct, or whether we are facing something more fundamental.

Comment: Sleep 120 doesn't work neither

Comment: Can you replace "allow-hotplug" with "auto" in /etc/network/interfaces? This will bring up the network before any services that depends on it. (However this is NOT what "auto" means, see man 5 interfaces for more details.)

Comment: "Perpaphs the issue is my configuration - my ethernet network is up 5-15 seconds after xfce (and desktop env.) is up. I don't know why ubuntu works like this."

You don't ? Ask NetworkManager, or whoever wrote that ... #! 
If it is a wireless connection, good luck configuring it, if it is wired, you should NOT have it managed by NetworkMangler.

Comment: `read: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: read: connection reset by peer happend for me because of wrong port.
have a look at kheraud answer which mentions how to change the port.
systemd + ubuntu20.04 with different Port and non-default ssh keyfile work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the **delay_connect** option.

Full /etc/fstab line:

```
USER@HOSTNAME:/REMOTE/ /LOCAL/ fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Those `delay_connect`, `_netdev`, ... are correct but won't work unless you tweak the networking to come up exactly in (or before) that small time window, when the /etc/fstab is being processed. When the processing is over, and networking comes up later, you have to use the `mount -a` (or friends).

In most cases (and mine also) the `network-manager` caused the problem, since it brings the network up **after login** by default. It can be tweaked to bring it up earlier at boot time. If I remember correctly, all you need to do is to check the option `Available to all users` in the connection properties dialog (or, if you prefer command line, create manually the connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) and my tries with Debian 9, I make it work and have right file permissions with this `fstab` entry :

```
sshfs#user@host:/remote/path /local/path fuse delay_connect,defaults,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/local/path/to/privatekey.pem,port=22,uid=1001,gid=1002,allow_other 0 0
```

`delay_connect` ensures `fstab` does not mount remote folder before network interfaces are up.

You can change `port`, `uid`, `gid` to match your local needs. To figure out my `uid` / `gid` I simply used `$ id` when logged with the right user.

`allow_other` is there to allow other users / groups to access the mounted directory; Even with the right `/local/path` permissions (for example `777`), this is needed if you want a different user (different from the one mounting the sshfs) to access the mounted directory.

Other options can be found in the [sshfs manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)

Comment: The options can indeed be found in the manpage, however what is not clear to me is how to write those options in the `fstab` file. Do you just write them without the `-o`, but otherwise identical, in the comma separated list of options of `fstab`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @MariusMatutiae is good, but I think it lacks a very important point. In the given [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS) to the Arch Wiki it says.

> And most importantly, use each sshfs mount at least once manually while root on the client machine so the host's signature is added to the client's /root/.ssh/known_hosts file. This can also be done manually by appending one or more of the the SSH server's public host keys (the /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*key.pub files) to /root/.ssh/known_hosts.

Actually you don't have to mount your sshfs while `root` for that to work. It's enough to `sudo ssh yourserver` for it to add the public key to root.

I had it set up in an Ubuntu server a couple of years ago and I remember struggling with that, but didn't remember what the solution was.
Now I switched to OpenSUSE and I struggled again for the same reason, until I decided to read that Arch Wiki page. So maybe this helps someone else.